# How to print a MySQL database table in PHP using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, forum

I want to print all the rows on the table. Every row is an answer to a question in a forum. The user can delete rows.

I can get the whole table in the database. But i don't know how to get every row.

**The controller:**

```
for ($idAnswer=1; $idAnswer<=?; $idAnswer++){
    $data=getData($idCourse, $idForum, $idAnswer);
    $author=$data['author'];
    $answer=$data['answer'];
    $date=$data['date'];
    echo $author;
    echo $answer;
    echo $date;
    }
```

**The funtion:**

```
public function getData($idCourse, $idForum, $idAnswer) {
        //Conect
        try {
            $this->BD=new PDO($this->infoBD, $this->usuarioBD, $this->claveBD);
            $this->BD->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }catch(PDOException $e){echo $e; }
        //Get data    

            try {
                $sql=$this->BD->prepare("SELECT author, date, answer
                FROM   answers
                WHERE  idForum='$idForum' and idCourse='$idCourse' and idAnswer='$idAnswer'");
                $sql->execute();
                $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $data=$sql->fetch();
                if ($data!=null){
                return $data;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }catch (PDOException $e){
                echo $e;
            }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: Do you want to get single rows from db using `PDO`?

Comment: Use fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Comment: bub should answer this and get accepted

Comment: Actually it only partially answers the OP's question @FabioCosta.

Comment: If you need all rows in the table, you also need to remove the `WHERE` condition. You can do that conditionally, based on the parameters (if they are all `NULL` for example) or you can add a new method that returns all rows automatically.

Comment: You really need to read up on how to use [PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) because seeing things like `$idCourse` embedded in your query string is usually a sign of a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Also note that opening a db connection in your method is probably not very efficient; you should open a connection once and pass that around to the classes that need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fetch()` function returns you the next row from the result set. You need something like this to get all results:

```
while($data = $sql->fetch()) {
   echo ($data['author']);
   echo ($data['date']);
   //...etc...
}
```

Or you can use `fetchAll()` function which returns an array with each row from the result and you can use a loop top traverse the array and do whatever you want with each row.

Example with `fetchAll()`:

```
$data = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($data as $row) {
   echo $row['autor'];
   echo $row['date'];
  //do whatever you want with the row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: Adding an explanation will result in a better answer and may gain you IIP's