# How to print the whole database table from phpmyadmin using PDO in php file

Tags: php, database, pdo, phpmyadmin

I am trying to print the whole database in tabular format in a php file using PDO. i have this database stored in phpmyadmin. But there are a lot of rows in there like name,id, etc etc... I have this following php code. i already made a connection to the database and added require_once() in the page. But i dont know how to print all these values in a tabular method. like showing it in a way a normal database will look like.

```
$q="SELECT * FROM `employee`";

$sth = $odb->prepare($q);
$sth->execute();

while ($r = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        // code here
    }
```

Can someone help me to display the table properly. That is if i run it in browser, i should see a table instead of that ugly array format

Comment: 1. your database is _not_ stored in `phpmyadmin`, that does not store anything, it is only a database _client_. The database is stored inside the database _server_ which is a `MySQL` server here. 2. there are millions of examples alone here on SO on how to output entries of a relational database in a tabular form. I suggest you simply follow a few "getting started" tutorials about php and database programming. They _all_ answer your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a MySQL database table in PHP using PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655369/how-to-print-a-mysql-database-table-in-php-using-pdo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally each table should have his own format, but if you just want to pop all the data from the base inside a HTML table, you could do something like that :

```
$sql = 'SELECT * from page';
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(count($result)) {
    echo '<table><tr>';
    foreach ($rows[0] as $columnName => $value) {
        echo '<th>' . $columnName . '</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ($row as $value) {
            echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
        }
        echo '<tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

You could use this on each table you want to show.

Comment: Thnxx. u r a life saver